# set time out for reactstrap collapse

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to use reactstrap collapse instead of reactjs transition for sliding my div horizontally. because the height of div changes according to the content of that. so I can't use transition. now I need to set a duration for collapse animation but I couldn't find any solution. can anybody help me?

Comment: and what you tried?

Comment: I just added reactsrap's collapse. I need some thing like transition's timeout working on collapse @Justcode